# How to return Gradle Setting to its original state?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

So I'm trying to get the SHA1 code by running the signingReport command on gradle. I used the gradled option in the right corner.
[image]

But after running, whenever I click Run button, signingReport command is executed and not Run command

[image]

The options change from Run 'App' to Run'Danaku[signingReport]'

I've tried several options, such as `gradle :app:assembleDebug` `gradle --build-file`  `gradle app` but nothing works

Anyone know how to change it back so i can run my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it here back to **app** with Android icon
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD0eV.png)

(I'm not allowed to add pictures so it's as a link)